# Puppet fill template values using params.pp complex data structures

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, puppet, wso2-as

I have the following data structure in my `params.pp` file at `/etc/puppet/modules/appserver/manifests`

```
class appserver::params {
        $servers = {
                appserver-mgr => { axis2   => {subDomain => 'mgt',},
                                   carbon  => {subDomain => 'mgt',},
                                   serverOptions => '-Dsetup',  },
                appserver-wkr => { axis2   => {subDomain => 'worker',},
                                   carbon => {subDomain => 'worker',},
                                   serverOptions => '-DworkerNode=true',  },
        }

        $serversDefaults = {
                clustering => 'true',
        }
}
```

In my template file (`axis2.xml.erb` at `/etc/puppet/modules/appserver/templates`). I have to fill the following field.

```
<property name="subDomain" value="<%= @subDomain %>"/>
```

How can I fill this subDomain value using the above data structure in `params.pp` file?

Comment: In other words, how do I write my init.pp file accordingly to access subDomain key value and fill the axis2.xml.erb file content.
I have imported the params.pp file as follows to the init.pp file.
`class appserver inherits appserver::params {
...
}`

Comment: do you need generate records for each subDomain, or just one of them, for example, for `appserver-mgr.carbon`?

Comment: yes. say its for appserver-mgr.carbon. The value to be written is 'mgt'.
How do I access this value and replace with the template @subDomain from this data structure.
It should look like <property name="subDomain" value="mgt"/>

Comment: I have accessed the data structure in the following way.
`notify { $servers[appserver-mgr][carbon][subDomain]:}`
I can access the value from my init.pp file.
How do I use it to fill a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash translates to Ruby quite literally.

```
<property name="subDomain" value="<%= @servers['appserver-mgr']['carbon']['subDomain'] %>"/>
```

This assumes that `$servers` has the value of `appserver::params::server` in the scope of the template expansion.

Comment: Yes, I proved it works. Could you please share me any tips on how to do the hash translates in ruby, any url or documents I can read?

Comment: If you assign a hash value to a Puppet variable, it will be a Ruby Hash when used in a template. For information on how to handle hashes in Ruby, I recommend the [reference documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html). Ruby Hashes have a multitude of methods that you can use. Also consider the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) mixin, from which the Hash gains even more methods that may be of use.